# Formatting text while passing props inside Object or Tag declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, tags

I am passing a tag like this: (in React)

```
<MainCard
    title="This is Title Text"
    subTitle="Hello World! This is Subtitle Text"
/>
```

Here, I want to make 'Hello World!' emphasized that is, show it in italics. How do I write it?

I have tried:

```
subTitle={<em> + "Hello Wolrd!" + </em> + "This is Subtitle Text"}

subTitle={"<em> Hello World! </em> This is Subtitle Text"}
```

But none of them works as expected.
Could you please tell me how do I achieve this?

Comment: How do you render `subTitle`props in the `MainCard`component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your text within a Fragment and pass it down as a react node like

```
subTitle={
    <React.Fragment><em> Hello World! </em> This is Subtitle Text</React.Fragment>
}
```

Working snippet

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const MainCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { props.title }
      <br/>
      { props.subTitle }
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <MainCard title="Vivek" subTitle={<React.Fragment><em>Hello World</em> Hi there</React.Fragment>} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about <React.Fragment>

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you can do it something like this:

```
subTitle={(<em>Hello World</em>)}

// OR for multiple element

subTitle={([<em>Hello World</em>, " Hi there" ])}
```

---

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { props.title }
      <br/>
      { props.subTitle }
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Main title="Vivek" subTitle={([<em>Hello World</em>, " Hi there" ])} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```